# Rails 5 filtered parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am migrating my 4.2 app into Rails 5 and I run into a strange problem. When I try to log in via this:

```
<%= password_field_tag :password %>
```

I got *[FILTERED]* log in server console, but I got *params[:pasword] =>* "*****" in controller. Which is of course not matching password (I am using BCrypt).

password encrypting:

```
  def encrypt_password(pass)
    BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret(pass, password_salt)
  end
```

When I pass string "*****" into this method I got the same result as if I pass *params[:password]* there, which means the controller doesn't know about inserted password but gets only 5 asterisks.
If I try this on my master branch with Rails 4.2.7 then in controller I can correctly see inserted password (in log there is "[FILTERED]" correctly).

Do I miss some new feature about filtering parameters in Rails 5???

EDIT:
I tried

```
render plain: params.to_yaml
```

I got:

```
--- !ruby/object:ActionController::Parameters
parameters: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
  utf8: "✓"
  authenticity_token: 6/qK4IYcTL3lDTLNEICMmrcBhR5FJy6r3QNN5hYXNQTOqrdwtcX5aye4wN3AIz6PSmsMSf6V7/z8fmUo7KUXyQ==
  login: doktor
  password: "*****"
  commit: Přihlaš
permitted: false
```

Comment: The `[FILTERED]` appearing in your log isn't new to Rails 5, this has been around forever: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#log-filtering

Comment: Try to replace your controller action with `render text: params` and see if you're able to see `params[:password]` in the browser

Comment: @ArunKumar I updated my question... it is not visible there...

Comment: @meagar I know that log is correct, those 5 asterisks are what bothers me...